# Maven: Is there any way to pull and checkout to specified branch of git repositories, if repository is already present on specified directory?

Tags: maven, maven-scm, maven-scm-plugin

Can maven does following?

1. Clone a repository with branch (Release-1.0) using maven-scm-plugin to specified target directory.(target/additional)
2. Do not clean target directory and update pom.xml (clone same repository at same directory just change branch to Release-1.1). Can maven just Pull and checkout the local repository with branch Release-1.1.

Say:

Step 1: Using pom.xml clone a repository with branch Release-1.0
Step 2: Update pom.xml with same repository just different branch Release-1.1.

If, I use configuration (skipCheckoutIfExists) then Maven is not updating remote repository with changed branch i.e Release-1.1

If i don't use skipCheckoutIfExists, it just overrides the old remote repository.

Can anyone give me alternate solution for this issue?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your steps. Which `pom.xml` should be updated?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JFMeier I have updated question for better understanding. Let me know if any other explainations are also required.

Comment: Why do you need to update a pom from a different release branch?

Comment: @JFMeier If i want latest source then I would need to change branch in pom

Comment: Wouldn't you just merge the other branch into your's?

Comment: Maven should pull from remote repository and then checkout the branch by this maven will take less time. @JFMeier